# Bootstrap Large Dropdown Menu CSS moving left or right based on window size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhdvgwe89ayda8c/Screenshot%202014-09-17%2015.27.20.png?dl=0

Above is an image of what I have explained in the title.

Here is an image when I increased the window size:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2dgdmrdwgz8cdn7/Screenshot%202014-09-17%2015.27.52.png?dl=0

As you can see the header and dropdown menu are on the same Y-axis and on the other end they're the same too.

If I make it bigger, it moves the opposite direction.

How can I have the large dropdown menu for each list item in my navbar dropdown the same container with the same width as the navbar as seen in the 2nd picture?

I want the width to remain the same regardless of window size.

Comment: Without seeing the code, I can't really say much, but I'm guessing that the header and dropdown menu should be in a wrapping container, apply the required styles to that container when it grows or shrinks and maybe add `float:left;` to the header?

Comment: It seems like the navbar is responsive but the dropdown menu is not.

Comment: No code still? Please provide us with the code to recreate this problem.